# how to count total number of ajax response data sets inside for loop?

Tags: javascript, ajax

i am calling an ajax and output api response in textbox. I want count total number of data sets received(counteri) and display it each time i click a button. For example if i click the button first time i want to an alert display counteri=20 and next time i click button it display counteri=40 and... counteri=60.

Currently my code keeps showing 20 each time and not adding the values. could any one tell me how to fix this.Thanks

```
 <script>
            var maxnumId = null;
            var counteri= null;
            function callApi() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    cache: false,
                    url: "https://api.somesite.com/......"),
                    success: function(data) {
                  maxnumId = data.pagination.next_num_id;

               for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

$(".galaxy").append("<div class='galaxy-placeholder'><a target='_blank' href='" + data.data[i].link +"'><img class='galaxy-image' src='" + ok.images.standard_resolution.url +"' /></a></div>"); 

                     document.myform.outputtext.value = document.myform.outputtext.value+data.data[i].images.ok.url+'\n' ;
                        //alert('www!'+i);  
                       counteri=i;
                    }

                    }

                });
              counteri=counteri+counteri;     
                alert('counteri is now: ' + counteri);
            }
            </script>
            <body>
            <br>
            <center>
            <div id="myDiv"></div>
        <div class="galaxy"></div>
            <button id="mango" onclick="callApi()">Load More</button>

            </html>
```

**EDIT:**
Adding this in start of success added up total number of records from ajax response

```
var num_records = Object.keys(data.data).length;
num_records2=num_records2+num_records;
alert('number of records:'+ num_records2);
```

**and**

```
var num_records2 =null; // outside function
```

Comment: There is an extra `}` just after the for. Can you check if it works removing it?

Comment: @Custodio I don't think that's an extra bracket - I see 4 total open brackets and 4 close brackets, so it all seems to line up.

Comment: @neuronaut .. yeah, you are right. I'm indentation blind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax are async calls.

Move the alert to just after the for. Not outside the success callback.

Comment: i tried your suggestion. If i put the alert after for the alert never pops up!

Comment: Cool! It's good actually.
Put a `complete` instead of `success` then. You are probably getting an error.

Comment: i put complete instead of success now i don't get any data from api at all!no alert popup either!

Comment: Put an `alert(data)` there right after the `complete`. You must receive something, otherwise something is really wrong with jquery...api or some other component.

Comment: @Custodio the initialization of variable `counteri=null` doesn't affect the functionality of the code. Please see this example http://jsfiddle.net/vasilenicusor/hqu9qhzn/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that you are setting `counteri` to the value of `i` instead of adding the value of `i`. Try this instead:

```
counteri += i;
```

Comment: thanks for reply.i need to store last value of i outside function(named it counteri) so that i can use it to add it up with next value of i! your solution give me totally incorrect total!(huge number)

Comment: @user1788736 if you will add more details about the requirements, you will get a bet answer faster. We don't know that you need the last value of `i` outside of ajax function starting  from your details

Answer (score 0):

Ajax calls are asynchronous. You should increment your counter on success, not outside of the ajax call. Something like this:

```
        function callApi() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            url: "https://api.somesite.com/......",
            success: function(data) {
              maxnumId = data.pagination.next_num_id;

              for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                document.myform.outputtext.value = document.myform.outputtext.value+data.data[i].images.ok.url+'\n' ;
              }
              counteri=counteri+i;     
              alert('counteri is now: ' + counteri);
            }
          });
        }
```

Comment: thanks for reply. if add alert just after for the alert never pops up!

Comment: If you are using Chrome, press CTRL+SHIFT+I

Answer (score 0):

Considering that your ajax request is executed with success, to get what you want you need to declare the `i` variable before `for ( ....)` loop as is the follow script:

```
var counteri = 0;
function callApi() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            url: "https://api.somesite.com/......",
            success: function(data) {
                var i,
                    maxnumId = data.pagination.next_num_id;
              for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                document.myform.outputtext.value = document.myform.outputtext.value+data.data[i].images.ok.url+'\n' ;
              }
              counteri=counteri+i;     
              alert('counteri is now: ' + counteri);
            }
          });
        }
```

[Please ses here demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vasilenicusor/u4bd8c84/1/)

**EDIT**

Also i have rechecked if the variable `i` is not declared before `for(...)` loop and works OK. So, the only fix is to remove `counter=i` from `for(...)` loop and to change the `counteri=counteri+counteri;` to `counteri+=i;`

Take in consideration that the ajax requests produce a number of different events that you can subscribe to. Depending of your needs you can combine this events to accomplish the desired behavior. The complete list of ajax events is explained [here](https://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)

**EDIT2**

After reading your comments, i see that you need the last value of `i` globally,
you need to add a second global variable too keep the sum of last `i` during all ajax requests.
To do this, id have added a minor change to answer:

```
var counteri = 0,
    totali =0;
function callApi() {
          $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            cache: false,
            url: "https://api.somesite.com/......",
            success: function(data) {
                var i,
                    maxnumId = data.pagination.next_num_id;
              for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                document.myform.outputtext.value = document.myform.outputtext.value+data.data[i].images.ok.url+'\n' ;
              }
              counteri = i;
              totali = totali + i;     
              alert('totali is now: ' + totali );
            }
          });
        }
```

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vasilenicusor/aL7172z2/4/)

**EDIT 3**

After your last comment, you need to add in the API response the number of returned rows. For this, you need to change `for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {` to something like this:

```
var num_records = data.num_rows;
for (i = 0; i < num_records ; i++) {
```

or, without adding the number of rows in response

```
var num_records = Object.keys(data.data).length;
for (i = 0; i < num_records ; i++) {
```

Comment: Thanks i tried your solution but no alert popup now!

Comment: @user1788736 if you open the debugger of browser, with F12, what you see on console tab when you perform an ajax request?

Comment: i get api response onload and when click button but the alert never pops up! in console i see data.data.[i] is undfined

Comment: i edited my first post. i forgot to write i have another append to div inside for loop after commented out i see alert shows up but instead of adding 20 each time it adds 100 this time.(20 is the number of records each time recived by api but 100 is number of loops).Problem is that i dont know how many records api sends me each time. It is not always 20 some time it is less but it never reaches 100.That is why i put for loop maximum number to 100 so i dont miss any records! is there any way to fix this issue and  add number of records instead of adding 100?

Comment: @user1788736 You should add the number of records in response, take a look on my EDIT 3

Comment: Thanks. How i can add up number of records and alert it each time i call the function ?for example 20+20+4=44 records for 3 clicks ?